# Legitimate methods for attracting attention to an old unansweed question

Tags: discussion

I asked a complex analysis question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437598/conjecture-every-analytic-function-on-the-closed-disk-is-conformally-a-polynomi) that got a number of views but no comments or answers.  I am aware that some questions just do not attract the interest of the SE community, but I feel that this one probably should, since it has to do with a very basic and interesting property of analytic functions.

I am worried that since it has been several days since posting, new people will not be looking at it.  I of course do not want to just repost the question to avoid cluttering the site.  I did edit it to rephrase it as a conjecture, but still do not have an answer.

Given that I do not have enough reputation to post a bounty, is there any legitimate way to attract new attention to my question?

Comment: and by the way, it's not hard to earn some rep by answering a few questions, especially for a grad student...

Comment: There ya go buddy.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thanks, I think that gave me the boost I needed, and I can now offer my own bounty as well.

Answer (score 11):

There are two ideas that come to mind.

1. Improve the question: add diagrams, background, show more work, etc.
2. [Start a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).