# Looking for An Answer

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, asking-questions

I was not sure whether to ask this question here or delete my question and ask the question again.

The problem: I asked a question a while back but I am still waiting for an answer. I was not sure what to do. Can I ask it here just so it can get some more exposure, or should I delete it and ask the question again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What question are you referring to?

Comment: @Thomas Hello, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965451/what-is-the-necessary-and-sufficient-condion-for-a-laplacian-to-be-zero this is the question.

Comment: You can put a bounty on it. I don't agree that meta should be used to increase the exposure of a question

Comment: @YuiToCheng I kind of agree with you.

Comment: @YuiToCheng btw, how can I put bounty on it?

Comment: Below all the comments on the question, do you see 'start a bounty'?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Got it thank you. Is 50 enough?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost It depends on how eager you are to know the answer and how willing you are to sacrifice your points (reputation).

Comment: @YuiToCheng I see, I will try 50 first hopefully I will get an answer.

Comment: See also: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478), [Legitimate methods for attracting attention to an old unansweed question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10251) and [several other related posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you very much for that.

Comment: Specifically for the part about deleting the question and asking it again, I should have linked to: [Can I ask the same question twice?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I ask it here just so it can get some more exposure, or should I delete it and ask the question again.

Generally, that's at least frowned upon, and I've seen people punished for insistently doing that, at least in a short time frame. Granted, that's on the main site - on Meta I can firmly say it wouldn't be allowed whatsoever, considering the nature of Meta. Meta is not meant to be used for exposure or anything, simply for discussion about the site.

Your best bets to increase exposure for the question:

- Perhaps editing in any relevant context into the body of the question. That will bump the question in the active questions list, if I remember correctly, and will in turn give it a bit of exposure.
- Putting a bounty on such a question is always an option, [as you have done](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965451/what-is-the-necessary-and-sufficient-condion-for-a-laplacian-to-be-zero).

It's not much but it's the best you really have for the time being. Asking on Meta is certainly to get you into trouble - though one would argue at least this post about it grants some exposure, even more in light of the bounty. Deleting and reasking is at *best* frowned upon if noticed, and could get you in trouble, and isn't going to help you any more than the editing bump or Bounty would.

I do hope your question gets an answer though. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking the same. That is why i didn't link my question in the body lest people think I am trying to do just that. But thank you for the information, I do hope i get an answer.